# Node JS: How to release a connection from the pool in MySQL2?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysql2

Please check my below code

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host: prop.get('server.host'),
  user: prop.get("server.username"),
  password: prop.get("server.password"),
  port: prop.get("server.port"),
  database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});

exports.getCountryList = (event, context, callback) => {
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "select * from country_list";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      log.console(err);
      var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
      callback(null, response);
    }
    else {
      var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
      };
      callback(null, response)
    }
  });
};
```

I am creating a connection pool, getting a connection from it, and executing the SQL statement. Does this connection get released automatically and immediately after the job? If not how can I release this connection?

At the same time, the way I am taking a connection from the pool is accurate?

Comment: Did you read [the fine manual](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools)? It answers both of your questions.

Comment: @robertklep: Thank you Robert. I am a senior engineer but novice to JS. Since the application I work on is on production, I expect to have some human to human advice. I will read the manual now. I appreciate if you can share your expertise with me in an answer as well.

Comment: @robertklep: I did read the manual. So the connection get auto resolved. Is that "immediately" after the query is done? Or will it wait for sometime, which will result in "running out of connections" when the same API call is hit again and again?

Comment: Your question isn't about JS, it's about an external library. As with any other programming languages, I would expect a senior engineer to first read the manual before asking questions. If you now have other questions, please augment your post.

Comment: @robertklep: The reason for me to ask that question is, I have used `con = await mysql.createPool`, following `con.getConnection()`. Technically the connections get closed automatically but I realized it takes few seconds so I had to manually release them with `connection.release()`. Just dont want to make the same mistake here.

Comment: Again, if you have a different question, please either update your post or create a new one. I don't understand why you would `await mysql.createPool` when it's not asynchronous, or why it would "follow" `con.getConnection`, or why you would call `release()` on a pool connection instead of returning it to the pool, as explained in the documentation.